# whatsapp chat API not working

Tags: php, whatsapi

I trying to make whatsapp message automatic with some data which i want from my server for that i am using whtsapi to implement the chat system with whatsapp. While I am trying to use the registration Example of chatAPI it is giving this message.Please Help
Thanks in Advance :)

```
<pre>


    Array 
  (
    [cc] => 91
    [in] => 88XXXXXXXXX
    [lg] => hi
    [lc] => IN
    [id] => 镅椒惮�eic"q鹵o}
    [mistyped] => 6
    [network_radio_type] => 1
    [simnum] => 1
    [s] => 
    [copiedrc] => 1
    [hasinrc] => 1
    [rcmatch] => 1
    [pid] => 3391
    [rchash] => cac5d887b8b826ee373ed950f1d7eb8c69f34fa3809c96cf0792cfa18074d4a0
    [anhash] => c98d49656ef76b4ecfb2cbb82d8bee17
    [extexist] => 1
    [extstate] => 1
    [code] => 123456
  )
  stdClass Object
   (
      [login] => 9188XXXXXXXXX
       [status] => fail
      [reason] => old_version
   )
</pre>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you paste some code?

Comment: the error is explicitly stated: `[reason] => old_version` probably you are using ChatAPI which is not maintaned after 2016 so whatsapp is refusing beacuse it is old.

Comment: Developer stopped public update of the Chat-API. Must be using it for life quote bot (as in Telegram) in a private way..  https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/issues/2116

Answer (score 2):

chatAPI (And as far as I know, no other Whatsapp API) no longer works because of the changes to Whatsapp's security system (end-to-end encryption).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  PHP Protobuf and Curve25519 to enable end to end encryption
as stated in the installation here
https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API

Comment: Hello,
thanks for your kind reply.

You did you ever use whatsapp api ?

Comment: No but worked on a workaround using whatsapp web and selenium